# Uitextfield notificaton xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode12

how do uitextfield appear message must be filled first before it can be executed?
I've searched Google but can't find it.

[my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGIGG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean display a message saying that the textFields must be filled before advancing?
If so, use an if statement on each textField

```
if namaField.text == "" || alamatField.text == "" || phoneField.text == "" {
    let alertController = UIALertController(title: "Enter all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    alert.addAction(okayAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: great, I will try

Comment: you should check textField empty with isEmpty variable: namaField.text.isEmpty

Comment: @goat_herd better to simply use `UIKeyInput` property `hasText` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext `if !(namaField.hasText && alamatField.hasText && phoneField.hasText) {`